# Why does this script run in Idle but not in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Trying to create a table to compare different methods of computing the square root of a number. Testing the script with integers from 1 to 9.

The script attached has previously run okay in Idle but now I have an additional error when I import tabulate. The script has never run successfully in Jupyter Notebook.

The only change when I run the code in Jupyter Notebook is that In [] changes to In [*].

I am new to Jupyter Notebook/Idle/Python in general. I understand In [*] means that the kernel is running but I don't understand why the computation would run okay in Idle and not in Jupyter Notebook.

Both programs were installed alongside Anaconda. Python is version 3.7.3. All modules used were installed in anaconda. OS is Windows 10.

```
'''Function to compare two methods of finding the square root 
of a value

'''This works in Idle but can not run in Jupyter Notebook. I don't understand why.

from tabulate import tabulate as tb
import numpy as np
import math

def mysqrt(a):

    #x = float(input('What is a reasonable estimate for ' + str(a) + '?\n'))
    #epsilon = float(input('What is your accuracy tolerance?\n'))

    x = a/2
    epsilon = 0.05

    while True:
        y = (x + a/x) / 2
        if abs(y-x) < epsilon:
            return y
            break
        x = y

def test_square_root():

    headers = ["a","mysqrt(a)", "math.sqrt(a)","diff"]
    table = np.zeros((9,4))

    for i in range(1,9):

        my_a = mysqrt(i)
        math_a = math.sqrt(i)
        diff = abs(my_a - math_a)

        print(np.shape(table[0,:]))
        table[i,:] = [i,my_a,math_a,diff]

    print(tb(table,headers))

test_square_root()
```

When the program has previously run in Idle it would output a formatted table with four columns and 10 rows, including header.

When I now run the script in Idle I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aIDAN\Documents\Python Scripts\Think Python\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tabulate import tabulate as tb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'
```

In Jupyter Notebook I receive no output or feedback, with only In [] changing to In [*])

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current problem is the tabulate module is not available in your python library.
It is a third-party package which does not come with the standard distribution of python

Use

> pip3 install tabulate

to install the tabulate module.

In Linux, the command to install tabulate module in user context is shown below.

```
[kuvivek@vivekcentos ~]$ python3.7 -m pip install tabulate --user
Collecting tabulate
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/fd/202954b3f0eb896c53b7b6f07390851b1fd2ca84aa95880d7ae4f434c4ac/tabulate-0.8.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: tabulate
  Running setup.py install for tabulate ... done
Successfully installed tabulate-0.8.3
[kuvivek@vivekcentos polls]$
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Unfortunately, I cannot use the pip3 command. I open Anaconda Prompt and type 
`pip3 install tabulate` 
but receive the response:
 `'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I realise I didn't specify in my original question but I am using Windows 10.

Comment: If `pip3` is not available, use `python -m pip install tabulate`

Comment: Got it sorted now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing dependency.
To solve the issue and install it use the command line, activate your Conda environment and write:

```
python -m pip install tabulate
```

Once that is done try to run the code again.